# Resize Div Based On Screen Size And Mantain Aspect Ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want made it responsive, fit on all screen size and mantain aspect ratio.

Demo link: http://yiedpozi.biz/yiedtest/

How can I do this? I would prefer Jquery than CSS because I think it's not suitable for my situation, such as using padding/margin top with percentage unit etc.

How can I do this with Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: You need all that yellow squares to have always the same width or the width can change when resize?

Comment: The width will change when resize. I want it to be small if screen size small.. So, it's fit that screen size.

Comment: No, you have to decide if the squares will resize or not. You have many ways to make a responsive layout. you can distribute your squares in thre, two, one column maintaining always the same width or you can change width. you have to decide it first

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without CSS.

```
@media screen only and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1366px) {
/* Here is the CSS code at 1280 - 1366 screen resolutions desktop */
}
```